# Is the support of a discrete random vector the Cartesian product?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

I'm confused on the notion of support of a discrete random vector.

Consider a discrete random variable $X$ which can take value in the set $\{0,1\}$ with strictly positive probability. Hence the support of $X$ is $\{0,1\}$.

Consider a discrete random variable $Y$ which can take value in the set $\{2,3\}$ with strictly positive probability. Hence the support of $Y$ is $\{2,3\}$.

Is the support of the random vector $(X,Y)$ necessarily the Cartesian product $\{0,1\}\times \{2,3\}$ or it can be a strictly subset of it?

I'm asking this because in my particular application some points of $\{0,1\}\times \{2,3\}$ are zero probability events when I consider the joint probability distribution of $(X,Y)$ and I'm wondering whether they should or they should not be part of the support of the random vector $(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The support of a random vector $(X, Y)$ may be strictly smaller than the product of supports of $X$ and $Y$. Imagine a situation where $X$ has a discrete distribution on $\{0, 1\}$ and $Y$ depends somehow on it, let's say $Y = X+1$.